# Mac OS X Disk Imaging Software

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation

I'm looking for some good disk imaging software, so I can store some of my Mac's applications on a flash drive and then export them to a newer machine. Any recommendations? Also, are there any free ones available?

Comment: Why do you need disk imaging software for that? Just copy the application from /Applications to the USB stick and carry it to the new machine. Or use a network connection or target disk mode.

Comment: I'm just basing this off what a friend had told me. But thank you, I will try that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Disk Utility.

You can use the New Image button in the toolbar to make a new disk image.

[image: SCreenshot of the Disk Utility toolbar with the New Image button circled.]

If you can be a little more specific as to what you want to do, I can be more specific as to how you'd use Disk Utility to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much! What my main goal is, is to put 5 applications I downloaded online onto a 16GB flash drive. A friend of mine told me that in order to do so, I need to convert the applications to disk images (.iso files). When that is completed, then I can put them on another Mac. Is that true?

Comment: No - just copy the apps

Comment: As mentioned above this is overkill. With a bit of luck you downloaded them as a .zip or a .dmg file which you can easily copy on any USB stick. Copying the app also works but may be more confusing (every .app is actually a folder).

Comment: @KenFedor patrix is right. If you don't have the source .zip or .dmg laying around and you want to be really particular, format the flash drive to HFS+ and stick the apps on it. (A Windows machine won't be able to read it, but you wouldn't need to have Mac apps on a Windows machine, anyway.)

Comment: Thank you everyone. I'm copying the .dmg's to my flash drive now.